# Debug using "attach to process" fails when Visual Studios 2008

Tags: debugging, process

Debugging works fine if i hit the F5 button but never when "attaching to process".

The process i take is:

1) In IE, i type in url: "localhost"

2) Default.aspx page opens

3) back to V.S. ->Debug->attach to process->w3wp.exe->attach it

4) if i have a break point on page_load, or anywhere else, it doesnt work.

I am using Visual Studios 2008 with IE 8, windows 7.

I have tried to change registery HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main

Put Value: DWORD TabProcGrowth Value 0
This doesn't help.

Any clues?

Comment: Are you attaching in the correct mode (ie native, managed, etc)?

Comment: Yes mate, its all fine - i've compared it to another pc's settings and it seems the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding some more notes:

I did notice on Visual Studio that "Script Documents" appears in the Solution Explorer ( which it never did in the past ).

I have deleted the Tempoary asp.NET cache files. This seemed to allow the "attach to process" debugging to work ( the first time the debugger ran ) but subsequently, the breakpoint would never be hit.